# how to get back to the tile page(start screen) after launching the ConnectionSettings Task in WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, tile

I am trying to launch the Connection settings task from the secondary tile. For that I am creating a tile and giving the uri as like

```
"ShellTile.Create(new Uri("/LaunchSettings.xaml", UriKind.Relative), standardTileData);".
```

In LaunchSettings.Xaml launching Bluetooth setting using URI Scheme. like

```
"await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings-Bluetooth:"));"
```

But once settings launched if I click back button, its coming to the LaunchSettings.xaml. Not returning to the Start screen. How to achieve that?

Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to exit the application in the `OnNavigatedToEvent`, so add the following override to your LaunchSettings.xaml.cs file:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back)
        Application.Current.Terminate();

    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}
```

Note that this will not trigger for example the `Application_Closing` event (see this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.application.terminate(v=vs.105).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Just write Application.Current.Terminate(); after the Launcher.

launches the Uri while closing your app.